# stride_tricks: numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError (How to accelerate the process of a custom template matching function)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, template-matching

I have a custom template matching function that is based on Zero mean Normalized Cross Correlation:
[ZNCC formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpPQm.png)

```
def ZNCC_mat(array1, array2):
    array1 = array1 / 255
    array2 = array2 / 255
    zmean_array1 = array1 - np.mean(array1)
    zmean_array1_norm = zmean_array1 / np.linalg.norm(zmean_array1)
    array2_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
        array2, window_shape=array1.shape
    )
    zmean_array2 = array2_view - np.mean(array2_view, axis=(2, 3), keepdims=True)
    zmean_array2_view_norm = zmean_array2 / np.linalg.norm(
        zmean_array2, axis=(2, 3), keepdims=True
    )

    result = np.einsum("ij,klij->kl", zmean_array1_norm, zmean_array2_view_norm)

    return result
```

Quick explanation:

1. normalize the gray images to have values between 0-1
2. subtract the template by its mean and divide by the std
3. use `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` to divide the source image into sub images/matrices
4. subtract each region by its mean and divide by the std
5. use `np.einsum` to compute the cross correlation between the zero mean normalized template and each zero mean normalized region of the source

However after computing **array2_view** it is very heavy to do operations on the submatrices. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/similarity_metrics_comparisons.py", line 17, in <module>
    result = ZNCC_mat(template_gray, source_gray)
  File "test/einsum_tests.py", line 145, in ZNCC_mat
    zmean_array2 = array2_view - np.mean(array2_view, axis=(2, 3), keepdims=True)
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 35.4 GiB for an array with shape (478, 1150, 97, 89) and data type float64
```

Any tips on what could optimize the operations?

if you want to run the code, with drawing a rectangle around the estimated position:

example of images:
[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0fS4.jpg)
[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zszmw.png)

```
#do not forget to read your source and template images
source = cv2.imread()
template = cv2.imread()
source_gray = cv2.cvtColor(source, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

result = ZNCC_mat(template_gray, source_gray)
print(result.max())
h, w = template_gray.shape
y, x = np.unravel_index(result.argmax(), result.shape)

top_left = (x, y)
bottom_right = (x + w, y + h)
cv2.rectangle(source, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), 2)

plt.subplot(131),plt.imshow(source)
plt.subplot(132),plt.imshow(result)
plt.subplot(133),plt.imshow(template)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Isn't ZNCC the same as OpenCV TM_COEFF_NORMED? See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d

Comment: `array2_view` is a view that uses indexing trickery to have a collection of sub-images based on one small chunk of memory. So even though it appear to contain some 5 billion floats, memory holds only some 550 thousand of them (and you see the same value in multiple positions). However, once you perform the subtraction, its result needs to be stored somewhere. At this point, reuse is no longer possible, since you're subtracting potentially different value from each layer of the view, so you need to allocate enough memory for all 5 billion.

Comment: You need to break up the job into chunks that are small enough to fit in your memory, and process those iteratively.

Comment: I hope those pictures are just arbitrary data, not representative of the actual task you're working on. 3D objects rotating in space (specific human heads) can't be matched like that. you will need AI. it already exists.